# How do we treat a column that has the same value across ALL records of a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, normalization

Assume that I have a table and to simplify things all rows are about `Persons`, and assume that we store the person's color. Now let's make the simplification that we have 1 million records and all persons' color is white.

Now in this case `white` is repeated over and over 1 million times.
Now if we can not change the table to be e.g. white_person table the way that it is, does it mean that the attribute `color` and `person` have a specific relationship that:

1. justifies the repeating attribute in the table?
2. justifies the creation of a new table and treating it as a `1-N` relationship? But formally how would this type of relationship be defined?

Answer (score 2):

If the same value is repeated on every row BECAUSE the dependency you actually wanted to model is ∅->{color} then your Persons table is in violation of 2NF: the determinant ∅ (the empty set) is a proper subset of a key. The change required to satisfy 2NF would be to remove the color attribute to a new table keyed on ∅ (i.e. a single row table). Or remove the attribute from the model altogether.

Note that a dependency is never automatically implied just because of a coincidence in some values in a table. What's at issue is what business rules you require the DBMS to enforce and whether the data model supports that properly.

I discussed a similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614144/deciding-whether-a-relation-is-3nf-or-2nf).

Comment: What is `∅->{color}`? I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: X->A means a functional dependency where the values of the attribute(s) X determine the values of A. If X is the empty set that means the value of A must be determined without reference to any other attribute and therefore the value of A is the same for every row.

Answer (score 1):

If a fact can be *assumed*, it doesn't need to be stored. So if there is a personal attribute whose value is known in advance, that you know **for sure** is same for all the people in the database, and will always stay the same in the future, then you don't need to physically store it in the database at all.

But I doubt you can make such an assumption. To lower the cost of storing the many repeated strings, separate the color to its own table with a slim [surrogate key](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info) (say, a byte or a 16-bit int), then reference it (via FOREIGN KEY) from the "big" table. This way, you are not repeating strings, you are repeating (slimmer) integers. This is not really a matter of normalization (both variants are "normalized"), but of optimizing the physical design.

However, if there is *another* attribute functionally dependent on color, then you should definitely have the separate table. Otherwise, there would be a [transitive functional dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_dependency) *PK -> color -> another*, violating the 3NF.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Branko: "If a fact can be assumed, it doesn't need to be stored". Should assumptions be built into code or persisted in the database? I'd say it depends. First weigh up the potential costs and risks of having to re-release code if/when assumptions change vs having to update an item of data in the database.

Comment: @sqlvogel I was making a rather philosophical point. The "assumption" I described never changes. The real world, of course, works differently.

Comment: +1:Interesting idea the reference to the other table.Is it a standard practice?

Comment: @Jin Database design is not a cookie-cutter proposition. You cannot just take a "standard practice" (whatever it might be) and apply it unconditionally. No design is perfect - it's always a tradeoff. I believe this particular design would be a decent tradeoff for your particular situation, but only you have the full extent of the information to make the final decision.

Answer (score 0):

> Now if we can not change the table to be e.g. white_person table the
>   way that it is, does it mean that the attribute color and person have
>   a specific relationship that
>
> 1) justifies the repeating attribute in the table?

*Repeating attribute* has a specific meaning in database technology. It does *not* mean you can find multiple rows that have the same value. (That's what rows are *for*.) You don't have a repeating attribute.

> 2) justifies the creation of a new table and treating it as a 1-N
>   relationship? But formally how would this type of relationship be
>   defined?

A 1-N relationship would be identified by a functional dependency--you'd find a person whose color is white and whose color is also fuschia. How many colors can a person be in your database?

Comment: 1) `It does not mean you can find multiple rows that have the same value. (That's what rows are for.)` I am asking about a value of a column being the same across all rows. Not all rows having the same values across all column. 2) `A 1-N relationship would be identified by a functional dependency` yes but you can have a separate table for a 1-1 relationship. That was my meaning but perhaps I wasn't clear

Comment: *"I am asking about a value of a column being the same across all rows."* And that's exactly what I'm talking about. That's what rows are for. You don't have a repeating attribute.