# How can this be in 3NF when through both keys the relation contains a partial functional dependency?

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf

> Relation schema: `R (ABCD)`
> Functional dependencies:
> `AB -> D`
> `CB -> D`
> `A -> C`
> `C -> A`
>
> What is the highest normal form?

My understanding:

Candidate keys are `AB` and `BC`.

While creating the table both `AB` and `BC` cannot both be primary key.

For key `AB`:
`AB -> D` (full functional dependency, so no problem)
`CB -> D` (?)
`A -> C` (partial functional dependency, as its left side contains only part of key)
`C -> A` (functional dependency, so no problem)

For key `BC`:
`AB -> D` (?)
`CB -> D` (full functional dependency, so no problem)
`A -> C` (functional dependency)
`C -> A` (partial functional dependency, as its left sideis part of key)

Through both keys the relation contains a partial functional dependency.
So it is not in 2NF.

But the answer is 3NF. Why?

Comment: "relation contains Partial Functional Dependency" is not enough to violate 2NF. Find & quote & use definitions of partial FD & CK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While creating table both AB and BC can not consider as Primary key.
>   So let's take one by one.

No. You can take them one by one, but you have to consider *every* candidate key. The relational model offers no theoretical basis for labeling one candidate key "primary". There might be good practical reasons for that in a SQL database, but there's no theoretical justification for it solely within the relational model.

The notion of "partial functional dependency" applies to non-prime attributes.  The only non-prime attribute is D. There's no partial dependency here.

Comment: A FD that holds is partial when dropping a determining attribute gives another FD that holds. That does not involve CKs or prime attributes. Every FD that has proper superset of a CK as determinant is partial; so there are partial FDs holding here, eg ABC->D. The partial FDs that matter to 2NF are ones where CKs determine non-prime attributes.

Answer (score 1):

1. When some FDs hold, others must hold, per Armstrong's axioms. But you are only looking at *given* FDs.
2. "Partial FD" is not defined in terms of CKs (candidate keys). 2NF is defined in terms of partial FDs and CKs. 2NF holds when there are no partial FDs of non-prime attributes on any CK. Not when there are no partial FDs.
3. PKs (primary keys) are irrelevant. A PK is just some CK you decided to call "the PK".
4. Y is partially functionally dependent on X when Y is functionally dependent on a smaller/proper subset S of X. But the partial dependency so identified is X -> Y, not S -> Y.

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25827210/3404097).)

Answer (score 0):

I can prove 3NF.
The reason of taking both **CK -> AB and BC** simultaneously given by Mike above
So, Now

> (A,B,C) are Prime Attribute (P.A) (i.e part of key)

&

> only D is Non-Prime Attribute (N.P.A) (i.e not part of key)

**Checking for 2NF**. there should not be any **P.A --> N.P.A** (i.e Partial F.D)

```
1)AB -> D (Key --> N.P.A)
2)CB -> D (Key --> N.P.A)
3)A-> C   (P.A --> P.A)
4)C -> A  (P.A --> P.A)
```

So, This is in 2NF.

**Checking for 3NF**. there should not be any **N.P.A --> N.P.A** (i.e Transitive F.D)

```
1)AB -> D (Key --> N.P.A)
2)CB -> D (Key --> N.P.A)
3)A-> C   (P.A --> P.A)
4)C -> A  (P.A --> P.A)
```

So, This is in 3NF

**Checking for BCNF**. there should not be any **P.A --> P.A** (i.e LHS only Key allow)

```
1)AB -> D (Key --> N.P.A)  ok
2)CB -> D (Key --> N.P.A)  ok 
3)A-> C   (P.A --> P.A)    not a key
4)C -> A  (P.A --> P.A)    not a key
```

So, This is not BCNF

So, Highest is indeed 3NF.

Comment: See the reasoning problems in my answer.

Comment: Means you are saying the above is not in 2NF?  partial F.D is dependent on part of the key right as per your 4th point? Can you show me any Partial F.D?

Comment: I am saying your reasoning is unsound. Eg PKs don't matter, CKs do. Eg Partiality is not about prime attributes determining but about proper subsets of CKs determining. Eg you list the given FDs that hold, but what matters is all the FDs that hold & the given ones imply others. Eg 2NF is not "there should not be any prime attributes partially determining a non-prime attribute". Etc. You clearly fail my answer points. PS Your reasoning is also not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Don't abuse symbols, use clear prose.

Comment: Re using technical terms correctly: [correct definitions & use of terms & symbols for FDs, partial FDs, 2NF & 3NF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27504915/3404097).