# Database Normalization mistake

Tags: database-normalization, functional-dependencies, third-normal-form

I'm preparing an exam and on my texts I found an example I don't understand.

On the Relation `R(A,B,C,D,E,F)` I got the following functional dependencies:

```
FD1 A,B -> C
FD2 C -> B
FD3 C,D -> E 
FD4 D -> F
```

Now I think all The FD are in 3NF (none is in BCNF), but the text says FD1 and FD2 to be in 2NF and FD3 and FD4 to be in 1NF. Where am I making mistakes (or is it the text wrong).

I found alternative keys to be ABD and ACD

Comment: You mean CKs (candidate keys) not AKs (alternate keys) (not "alternative").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Terminology**

It is highly improper to say that: “a Functional Dependency in is in a certain Normal Form”, since *only* a relation schema can *be* (or not) in a Normal Form. What can be said is that a Functional Dependency *violates* a certain Normal Form (so that the schema that contains it is not in that Normal Form).

**Normal forms**

It can be shown that a relation schema is in BCNF if every FD given has as determinant a superkey. Since, has you have correctly noted, the only candidate keys here are ABD and ACD, every dependency violates that Normal Form. So, the schema is not in BCNF.

To be in 3NF, a relation schema must have all the given functional dependencies such that either the determinant is a superkey, or every attribute of the determinate is a prime attribute, that is it is an attribute of some candidate key. In your example this is true for B and C, but not for E and F, so FD3 and FD4 violates the 3NF. So, the schema is neither in 3NF.

The 2NF, which is only of historical interest and not particularly useful in the normalization theory, is a normal form for which the relation schema does not have functional dependencies in which non-prime attributes depend on part of keys. This is not true again for FD3 and FD4, so that the relation is neither in 2NF.

Comment: Furthermore re impropriety: When we say that a FD violates a NF we really mean that [it violates (some conjunct of) a particular definition of the NF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45222622/3404097). A FD can violate per one definition yet not violate per another. So just saying some particular FD violates the NF means it violates (some conjunct of) some definition the speaker has in mind, but it doesn't allow us to confirm that; we need to know the definition.

Comment: Thanks, the point I was missing was on the definition of 2NF, whan it says 'the determinate must depend on the whole key', I thought that all the determinant, shouldn't contain non prime attributes, when actually is the determinant that should contain all the key attributes.  Anyway thank you!