# How can I create partial dependency in a many to many relationship?

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I am dealing with normalization and I have encountered a problem. In my normalization report, I need to demonstrate at least one partial dependency and transitive dependency. I started with ER modelling, therefore, almost all of my tables are in the BCNF form. Now, I have a many to many relationship and I need to ruin this table to normalize. Yet, I cannot find any way to change it to the version that I can normalize. What do you think that I can add as an attribute which will cause partial dependency?

[Table with composite primary key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tanD.jpg)

Comment: Any presentation of partial FDs including your textbook & SO questions likely gives an example. Also any definition of partial FD describes them. Please start there. An answer has to. Please don't expect others to do everything. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partial Dependency(Databases)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747802/partial-dependencydatabases)

Comment: Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. PS "No partial FDs" is not a definition of 2NF. PS What is your 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question?